# write error (file system full?) on fc 18

Tags: linux

I'm not able to edit any file on my linux machine. 
I checked the free space available on my system,

```
    df -h
    Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    devtmpfs                  16G     0   16G   0% /dev
    tmpfs                     16G   84K   16G   1% /dev/shm
    tmpfs                     16G   18M   16G   1% /run
    tmpfs                     16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    /dev/mapper/fedora-root   50G  4.9G   42G  11% /
    tmpfs                     16G   40K   16G   1% /tmp
    /dev/mapper/fedora-home  428G  428G     0 100% /home
    /dev/xvda1               477M   90M  358M  21% /boot
```

"/dev/mapper/fedora-home" is consuming complete memory, I'm not sure what this file signifies. How can I free the space consumed by this?

Comment: df is showing you free disc space, not memory.

Answer (score 10):

That's the partition where your home directory is located; since it's full, you won't be able to create new files anywhere under `/home`.

Delete some files in your home directory to free up space.  If there are other users on the system, ask them to delete files they don't need as well.

Comment: I dont have files that consumes 428G in home directory. Is there a command to defragment?

Comment: You're not losing nearly half a terabyte to fragmentation; something's taking up that space.  Run `du -sch $HOME/*` to see the actual size of everything in your home directory.  If it doesn't add up to around 428G, run it as root on `/home/*` to see what's outside your own home directory.

Comment: Total 4.5G is consumed when I run "du -sch /home/*".

Comment: Did you run that as root?  If not, you probably don't have permission to see files in other users' home directories.  But if you really have only 4.5GB of files, the filesystem may be corrupted; you may need to run `fsck` on it.

Comment: This sort of troubleshooting is off-topic for StackOverflow, by the way.  [Super User](http://superuser.com/) is a more appropriate place to ask.

Comment: Ya I ran it as root, thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Run the following commands to find big files in your $HOME

```
find ~ -type f -exec du {} + > /tmp/size_report.txt
sort -rn /tmp/size_report.txt | head -n20
```

and delete what you don't need from that list. Change the number from 20 to whatever to see more files.